# Deshabilitar alertas de dependencias en Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy usando la dependencia de `class-validator` y al agregarla me empezo a generar estas alertas.

Estas y bueno de esas así como unas 50

```
Warning: C:\Users\WDS\Documents\GitHub\Angular\cliente-app-day\node_modules\class-validator\esm2015\decorator\string\IsBase64.js depends on 'validator/lib/isBase64'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: C:\Users\WDS\Documents\GitHub\Angular\cliente-app-day\node_modules\class-validator\esm2015\decorator\string\IsCurrency.js depends on 'validator/lib/isCurrency'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

Me fui a la ruta de angular que me indica pero la verdad no entendí como usar esto y en que json de mi aplicación hacerlo si en package.son o package-lock.json o los demás
https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
     "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
        "lodash"
     ]
     ...
   }
   ...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar en tu **angular.json** lo siguiente, en el array "allowedCommonJsDependencies:

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
        "lodash",
        "validator/lib/isBase64",
        "validator/lib/isCurrency",
     ]
```

Con eso vas a eliminar los warnings.